Why is BeautifulSoup find_all() method stopping after HTML comment tag?
I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse this website:
https://www.baseball-reference.com/postseason/1905_WS.shtml
Inside the website, there's followig element
<div id="all_post_pitching_NYG" class="table_wrapper">

This element as wrapper should contain following elements:


<div class="section_heading assoc_post_pitching_NYG as_controls" id="post_pitching_NYG_sh">



<div class="placeholder"></div>


a very long HTML comment

<div class="topscroll_div assoc_post_pitching_NYG">



<div class="table_container is_setup" id="div_post_pitching_NYG">



<div class="footer no_hide_long" id="tfooter_post_pitching_NYG">





I have been using:
response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

pitching = soup.find_all("div", id=lambda x: x and x.startswith("all_post_pitching_"))[0]
for div in pitching:
   print(div)

But it only prints until the very long green HTML comment, then it never prints (4) or beyond. What am I doing wrong?

I'm going to guess this is because you fetched the html with requests or urllib which cannot process javascript, and that page depends on javascript.

I added some additional code to my post, I am using requests. What should I be using instead?

Most people use selenium for this.

i don't think you're needing selenium here. this long comment is probably the data you're searching for

Check special strings:

Tag, NavigableString, and BeautifulSoup cover almost everything you’ll see in an HTML or XML file, but there are a few leftover bits. The main one you’ll probably encounter is the Comment.

A simple solution could be to replace the comment characters in the HTML string to bring it up for BeautifulSoup:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/postseason/1905_WS.shtml').text.replace('<!--','').replace('-->','')
)

pitching = soup.select('div[id^="all_post_pitching_"]')[0]

for e,div in enumerate(pitching.select('div'),1):
   print(e,div)

An alternative to be more specific is the use of bs4.Comment
